# Splitting table column and using to update another table in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, table

I have a table (T1) which I need to populate (using python for ArcGIS) the fields Val1, Val2 and Val3

```
ID Val1 Val2 Val3

0

1

2
```

with data from another table (T2):

```
ID Data

0 V1

1 V1

2 V1

0 V2

1 V2

2 V2

0 V3

1 V3

2 V3
```

so the original table (T1) becomes:

```
ID Val1 Val2 Val3

0 V1 V2 V3

1 V1 V2 V3

2 V1 V2 V3
```

I currently do this using a SearchCursor nested in the UpdateCursor.

I thought a quicker solution would be to split T2 into three columns or a temporary table, and then update T1 using the update cursor.

Can anyone help me with this?

My code currently:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Flow_Paths) 
for row in rows:
    X_A = row.X_Cord_A # First X Cord
    Y_A = row.Y_Cord_A # First Y Cord   
    rows_i = arcpy.SearchCursor(point_shp) 
    for row_i in rows_i: 
        if X_A == row_i.xCentroid and Y_A == row_i.yCentroid: #Find upstream path lengths and extract maximum lengths, elevations, and min area
            ElevationMax = row_i.DEM
            AreaMin = row_i.CatchArea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is quite specific to the situation but will post in case it helps anyone else.

```
def SplitCol(Column,Splits):
Length = len(Column)/Splits
ta = np.zeros((Length,Splits))
tv = 0
for i in range(Splits):
    for j in range(Length):
        ta[j,i] = Column[tv]
        tv += 1
return ta


ColDEM =[]

rows_i = arcpy.SearchCursor(point_shp) 
for row_i in rows_i: 
    ColDEM.append(row_i.DEM)
del row_i
del rows_i

taDEM = SplitCol(ColDEM, 3)

tv = 0
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Flow_Paths) 
for row in rows:
    row.El_Max = taDEM[tv,0]
    row.El_Min = taDEM[tv,1]
    tv += 1
del row
del rows
```

I loop over the dbf and add the values to a vector (or column).  Then the SplitCol splits my T2 table in the question above into 3 columns.  I then loop over the dbf file and add the indexed results from the matrix as required.